# Scenekit - Add child node (Plane node) to the parent node (sphere node) in front of camera

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, scnnode, scnscene

I am trying to add child node to the parent node which have it's own camera. on tap of the user on scene, using hit test I am adding child node (i.e plane node) to the the parent node (sphere node). But I don't know why the child node is not facing properly to the camera. it's looking different on different location. I wanted it to fix looking at the camera.

Code :

```
// Creating sphere node and adding camera to it 

func setup() {

        let sphere = SCNSphere(radius: 10)
        sphere.segmentCount = 360
        let material = getTextureMaterial()
        material.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "sample")
        sphere.firstMaterial = material
        let sphereNode = SCNNode()
        sphereNode.geometry = sphere
        sceneView.scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(sphereNode)
}

 //Creating texture material to show 360 degree image...

func getTextureMaterial() -> SCNMaterial {
        let material = SCNMaterial()
        material.diffuse.mipFilter = .nearest
        material.diffuse.magnificationFilter = .linear
        material.diffuse.contentsTransform = SCNMatrix4MakeScale(-1, 1, 1)
        material.diffuse.wrapS = .repeat
        material.cullMode = .front
        material.isDoubleSided = true
        return material
    }




 @objc func handleTap(rec: UITapGestureRecognizer){
            if rec.state == .ended {
                let location: CGPoint = rec.location(in: sceneView)
                let hits = sceneView.hitTest(location, options: nil)

                if !hits.isEmpty {
                    let result: SCNHitTestResult = hits[0]
                     createPlaneNode(result: result)
                }

        }
}

func createPlaneNode(result : SCNHitTestResult) {
    let plane = SCNPlane(width: 5, height: 5)
    plane.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.red
    plane.firstMaterial?.isDoubleSided = true
    let planeNode = SCNNode()
    planeNode.name = "B"
    planeNode.geometry = plane
    planeNode.position = result.worldCoordinates
    result.node.addChildNode(planeNode)
}
```

Results I am getting using above code:

Added Plane node is looking weird

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you ever found your answer but, it would be done freeing the node axes with SCNBillboardConstraint :)

```
let billboardConstraint = SCNBillboardConstraint()
billboardConstraint.freeAxes = [.all]
node.constraints = [billboardConstraint]
```

Comment: will try out and get back to you.